# Backbone object does not have Wreqr property

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, browserify, shim

I am trying to get **Browserify** working **Marionette**. More precisely I'm trying to figure out how to require the commands Backbone.Wreqr.Commands.

I keep getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Commands' of undefined
```

With this code

```
Backbone = require('../shims/backbone');

module.exports = new Backbone.Wreqr.Commands;
```

This is my setup

**main.coffee** (browserify entry point)

```
app = require('./app')
Backbone = require('./shims/backbone')
commands = require('./config/commands')
```

**shims/backbone**

```
module.exports = Backbone
```

**shims/marionette**

```
module.exports = Backbone.Marionette
```

**config/commands**

```
Backbone = require('../shims/backbone')
module.exports = new (Backbone.Wreqr.Commands)
```

As you can see from above I decided to not use browserify for the main dependencies so essentially I'm including them in the page globally but then using these custom shims above to include them in my app.

The problem I'm having is it seems Wreqr does not exist on the Backbone object. I guess that sort of makes sense as I saw in the source this is added with the Marionette library.

But how exactly do I reference it here?

I found a somewhat related problem with require-js https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/1297

Comment: Use webpack instead, it's like 2000% faster at compiling

Comment: Holy dam!!! Thank you Dominic for the heads up the difference is huge.